# Issue with time in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, asp.net-core

I have an action that gets a post request and stores the JSON input into a MongoDB. The issue is I found some requests in database from one specific user in the same time zone (same city and the time zone is `EST`) but the stored time offset is different. The `Date` property is a date that user picks from a date picker and `CreatedAt` is set automatically in the back-end (`DateTime.Now`).

These are the stored times (look at the `Date` field):

```
{
   Id: 1,
   CreatedAt: 2023-03-15T21:20:02.682+00:00,
   Date: 2023-03-15T05:00:00.000+00:00
}
{
   Id: 2,
   CreatedAt: 2023-03-20T13:59:02.974+00:00,
   Date: 2023-03-15T04:00:00.000+00:00
}
{
   Id: 3,
   CreatedAt: 2023-03-20T14:04:30.999+00:00,
   Date: 2023-03-15T04:00:00.000+00:00
}
```

The `DateTimeOffset` in first record is different but I know the `day light saving` date was **March 12th**.

And here is the API code:

```
public class RequestModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task Create([FromBody] RequestModel request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    // Store request in database
}
```

I don't know what could be the reason.

Comment: The data does not match your description. It's mar 15th and 20th not 12th and offsets are the same : 00:00...

Comment: I'm not sure I got the question, but the reason why inserted date value can be not the same as the stored is because Mongo stores dates as UTC

Comment: @Fildor Daylight saving happened on March 12th but the data I got on March 15th came with +5 hours offset and on March 20th with +4 hours offset. I didn't get your point.